# Complex POJO mapping using Dozer

Tags: java, xml, mapping, pojo, dozer

I am new to Dozer, and have done flat mapping from one POJO to another using Dozer xml mapping.But now I want to map complex POJO which is given below and I am stucked how to do it.

```
    // -----------------------Source Classes-----------------------------

    public class Source{

    public String sourceId;
    public Product product;
    public List<Item> items;
}


public class Product{
    public Integer productId;
    public String productName;
}

public class Item{
    public Integer id;
    public Integer qty;
    public String desc;
}

  // -----------------------Destination Classes-------------------
public class Destination{

    public String destId;
    public DestProduct destProduct;
    public List<DestItem> destItems;
}

public class DestProduct{
    public Integer nProductId;
    public String sProductName;
}

public class DestItem{
    public Integer nId;
    public Integer nQty;
    public String sDesc;
}
```

How do I tell Dozer to map Source to Destination?

Answer (score 0):

You should check Dozer documentation. It has everything you need to map your classes.

I think you are worried mainly for below mappings:

**1. Map custom object fields and wrapper classes fields:**

Check the **Basic property mapping** in dozer documentation. Many data type coversions are performed automatically by the Dozer mapping engine. Check the below link for more info.
http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/simpleproperty.html

**2. List fields containing custom object mappings:**

This is explained at the below link:
http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/collectionandarraymapping.html#

For cases where a feature isn't supported out of the box, you can also write a custom converter:
http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/customconverter.html

Also, It will help to first write simple standalone programs to understand/test a particular mapping before jumping with implementation in your project.